# Empty CGContext

Tags: swift, core-graphics

In Objective-C I was able to use `CGBitmapContextCreate` to create an empty context. I am trying to to the same in Swift 3, but for some reason it is nil. What am I missing?

```
let inImage: UIImage = ...
let width = Int(inImage.size.width)
let height = Int(inImage.size.height)

let bitmapBytesPerRow = width * 4
let bitmapByteCount = bitmapBytesPerRow * height

let pixelData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount)

let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                                width: width,
                                height: height,
                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)
```

Comment: Tested your code and Xcode says in console **CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination**. Why are you specifying `CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue`(_There is no color data, only an alpha channel._) I believe you would get nil even in Objective-C with that parameter.

Comment: I am trying to rewrite this code into Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11637839/1757229. It is failing with any CGImageAlphaInfo value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the code in the liked article would do, but two things are different with your Swift code.

- `bytesPerRow: width // width * 4 (== bitmapBytesPerRow)`
- `space      : NULL  // CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()`

The [documentation of `CGBitmapContextCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455939-cgbitmapcontextcreate) does not say anything about supplying `NULL` for `colorspace`, but the header doc says **The number of components for each pixel is specified by `space`**, so, at least, `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` is not appropriate for `alphaOnly` (which should have only 1 component per pixel).

As far as I tested, this code returns non-nil `CGContext`:

```
    let bitmapBytesPerRow = width //<-
    let bitmapByteCount = bitmapBytesPerRow * height

    let pixelData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount)

    let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow,
                            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), //<-
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)
```

But, not sure if this works for your purpose or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I was working on this thing and faced same issue. 
The solution I found is to use

```
var colorSpace =   CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
  let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                            width: Int(outputSize.width),
                            height: Int(outputSize.height),
                            bitsPerComponent: self.bitsPerComponent,
                            bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow,
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
```

Actually my image's color space was Indexed Which can't be used to make a context.
So instead of using image's own colorSpace I made my own by using

```
var colorSpace =   CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
```

and passed it to the context.
it resolved my error (nil context issue).

Comment: Thanks for this!  I modified it just a bit.  I removed the colorSpace variable and put the call to CGColorSpace.init() directly in the space: option because I have no need for that property later on.  I also declared the context property as a class variable so I can actually assign the correct CGContext later on in a class method.  Great work!